# Data conversion failed in Sql server/SSIS/Excel due to truncation

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

[image]Im getting error while loading excel file to **Sql server** through **SSIS**.for only two column ( client , rue ) . the problem is my text is not even long . i have been searching everywhere and tried every solution but no results . here what i tried :

1- solution 1 : in data conversion i changed the type **unicode string  to string STR** and increase the **length** => failed

2- solution 2 => i changed data type in sql server from varchar(255) to varchar(max) then in data conversion i changed it from **unicode string to TEXT** => failed

3-solution 3 => i went through advanced setting and changed the output type , as well as **TruncationRowDiposit** : Rdignore failre . but still getting the same error

4- slution 4 => set the **TypeGuessRows** registry value to 0 in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** , this was my last attempt but failed

any other solution ? because i get the same error :
[17/03/2022 13:00]
**The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Le texte est tronqué ou un ou plusieurs caractères n'ont aucune correspondance dans la page de codes cible.".
The "Conversion de données.Sorties[Sortie de conversion de données].Colonnes[Copie de Nom Client]" failed because truncation occurred,**

[image][image][image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Considering that the error is occurring on the Excel Source, I smell that ACE is doing what it does best; making terrible decisions and assuming your column is smaller than is actually is.

Comment: In the advanced Editor, where did you change the length, on the External or Output Columns.

Comment: i change it in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same issue and I ended up changing my SQL Server Data Type from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR and that fixed my issue. I don't know why SSIS was doing this but changing to NVARCHAR fixed my issue.